# breeze js save changes completes before saving

Tags: javascript, breeze

I have the following issue where the breeze js (1.4.2) SaveChanges method is processing the 'then' promise before the save operation completes.

```
save()
{
    this.manager.SaveChanges()
        .then(process);
}
function process()
{
    var baseUri = "api/DoServerProcessingOnNewData";
    $.getJSON(baseUri, data =>
    {
        // Save operation is still running, and server processes old data
        this.items(data)
    })
}
```

I would have expected the 'then' part of the promise to execute once SaveChanges has fully completed? is this the expected behavior, can I detect when the save operation actually completes?

Comment: What evidence do you see that the SaveChanges hasnt completed?

Comment: the server api method called in the process func gets the old data i.e, before the save happened, Also now seeing that after a save the entity ID is not getting fixed up after the 'then' completes on save changes. if I add pause i.e. wait for the save changes to complete then all works fine, but I should be able to rely on the 'then' promise to notify me its complete.

Comment: Sorry, I can't repro the behavior that you see. Are you sure that you are called EntityManager.saveChanges ( lowercase "s")?

Comment: If the server api isnt getting the new data, the save will do nothing. Check your manager object has registered your entity changes by checking the entities' entityState.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved issue, I had wrapped the save changes call in my data service layer. Calling the EntityManager.saveChanges directly correctly processes the promise.

```
// Don't do this, wrap the saveChanges method
public static saveChanges() 
{
    return DataService.EntityManager.saveChanges();
}
```